# Open text file in custom created c# editor

Tags: c#

I have created a texteditor like notepad. I'm facing a problem in opening file when i try to double click the .txt file, texteditor opens but there are no content available in it.

[Opending file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hkwg.png)

On opening this file with my custom C# editor, the editor opens without content.
[Opend file without content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVP9e.png)

Comment: That would give you the file to open in the command line. Are you getting it right?

Comment: The filename should be given as an argument to your program - do you handle that?

Comment: No, I am new to C#, can you guide me how can i do that ?